# C# program runs too long mapping to an excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel

I have a C# program that takes a legacy report file and maps to an Excel. It was running ok but we changed the process. The legacy program groups all the detail rows together and my program breaks page rather than before when they provided all the pages. this had added to run time about 4 times as long.

I have been told that if I can manually modify Excel to create 'proper' output for input file, It  can speed things up a good bit.

also go to an Excel code-behind or add-in which would run from Dxcel and thus be faster

Can someone direct me how to apply these 2 ideas?
We do the code now as an array and write the entire row rather than cell by cell.
here is copy of the code:   http://www.mediafire.com/?cebg17u5wl0ir25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automation of Office applications is generally very slow. I just encountered this problem while trying to create a complicated graphic with Visio form c# code. It lasted about 30s. Now i create a SVG-File, that is then opened in Visio. Creating the SVG-File lasts less than 1s now!

I suggest that you export your data as CSV-File and then import it into Excel. Do only the minimum, i.e. the creation of worksheets, the import of the CSV and the formatting, with Excel-automation.

Comment: He wants page breaks in the file, so csv won't do it. But spreadsheetml might.

Comment: yes that is the need. In my C# I am doing the page break after 16 detail rows. Other wise if I have the legacy programmer send it with breaks, then we will need multiple programs there as well as more templates.